# Comparing Boolean Arrays: Count number of times BOTH are True

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, ambiguous, valueerror

I want to know how to count the number of true elements in multiple NumPy bool arrays. For example, on which trials do both A and B == 1. Below is what I have tried.

```
A = array([1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1])
B = np.array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1., 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0., 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0., 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1., 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0., 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0., 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0., 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1., 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0., 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.])

num_trials = len(A)
slide_avg = np.zeros(num_trials)

for i in range(num_trials):
    if i < num_trials_slide:
        slide_avg[i] = np.sum(A[0:i+1] == 1 and B[0:i+1] == 1)/float(np.sum(A[0:i+1] == 1))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Replace `and` with  `&`

Comment: Think it should be : `np.sum(( A[0:i+1] == 1) & (B[0:i+1] == 1))/float(np.sum(A[0:i+1] == 1))`.

Comment: Then I get the following error:    TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply element-wise multiply the arrays into a new array (e.g. C), the number of elements equal to **1** will be equal to the number of elements where both A and B are true.

```
len(np.where(A*B == 1)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

@AustinA has a very smart [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46716614/7954504) taking advantage of the fact that 1*1=1.

The one possible shortfall is for cases where you have non-integer values, i.e. a 2.0 and 0.5, which would evaluate to 1.0 under this logic.  If that's the case, an alternative would be:

```
np.sum((A == 1) & (B == 1))
# 24
```

But if you're working with all integers, @Austin's answer should be about 2x faster.